# How do you determine the last process to modify a file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I know how to get the user that last modified a file, but does Windows track the process that made the modification as well? If so, is there an API for looking that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not recorded.

You could enable Object Access Auditing on a particular folder (I wouldn't recommended using on the general file system). See this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericfitz/archive/2006/03/07/545726.aspx) and use with caution!

You might be able to use .NET's [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

You could use procmon.exe from https://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe
This is a live monitor, so not much use retrospectively.

1. Deselect (uncheck) the "File | Capture Events" menu item.
2. Clear the currently displayed events by selecting the "Edit | Clear
   Display" menu item.
3. Configure a filter by:

   a. Select the Process Monitor "Filter | Filter..." menu item. This will
      display the "Process Monitor Filter" dialog.

   b. Set a new filter by setting the "Display entries matching those
      conditions" fields:

   c. (pick)Path  (pick)contains `whatever.txt` then (pick)Include

   d. Click the "Add" button to add the new filter.

derived from instructions here: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3035

Answer (score 0):

Windows does NOT track the process that modifies a file.  Best you can hope for is to actively watch the file(s) you are interested in and take note when an application opens them.  I've seen applications that do this (eg. Sysinternals FileMon) but do not know off the top of my head how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine the process that is modifying the file during the runtime of your program, you could use the Windows API or a minifilter driver to track what every process on the system is doing (similar to using Sysinternals FileMon with custom filters, as Boo pointed out), but that will apply only during the runtime of your "capture" program. Once the file is modified, however, all the traces are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use Windows [security auditing](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericfitz/archive/2006/10/26/how-are-object-access-events-generated.aspx) to log access to the file?